# React radio button requires two clicks to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, controlled-component

I'm controlling a Radio button on a react form.

The state is updating on change as expected, but the `checked` value isn't being rerendered on change. Therefore, from a user perspective the button isn't working.

I've replicated this in a codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hertz-stzgk?file=/src/App.js

Relevant code:

```
const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState("staff");

...

  const handleRoleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelectedRole(event.target.value);
  };

...

<form>
        <label>
          Staff
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="role"
            value="staff"
            checked={selectedRole === "staff"}
            onChange={handleRoleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Student
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="role"
            value="student"
            checked={selectedRole === "student"}
            onChange={handleRoleChange}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
```

Appreciate any help as I'm out of ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Just get rid of `event.preventDefault()` in your `handleRoleChange` function and it will go like butter. https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-euler-6lfi9

Comment: try without `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @codemonkey , i can see it's working now. But could you explain why it acting like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of event.preventDefault() in 9th line which stops it to change it instantly

Edit 1: 2/5/2022:
you can also refer to: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Since you posted an answer vs a comment. Could you elaborate as to why this behavior occurs?

Comment: event.preventDefault() says that if the event has happened it should not proceed with default action but with an explicit one which it was able to proceed on the with second tap.

Comment: its generally used when you want to use the info from the given button(in this case) or send it to backend and want to perform any task, it blocks it and proceeds with the function you have below it, the same happened here, that is why removing it let your work flow go in a sequence and did not left anything behind

you can also refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I’m not sure why the controlled behaviour doesn’t work though. When the state changes on the onClick function it should re-render, and then the checked attribute will be recalculated. I don’t see why the default action is needed if react is controlling it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But why will it re-render if you are preventing it from re-rendering , you are preventing what it should be doing by default.

Comment: I see what you're saying @Ishan but to me it's still kinda counterintuitive because other things still rerender while the radio input doesn't change, for example had another input conditionally rendered which shows up as expected while the radio indicator didn't change. All of this shows I'm not using radio inputs frequently enough 